# Download of the Android Studio stops in Ubuntu 14.04 with in a few seconds.

Tags: software-installation, android, sdk

Tried to download the sdk from torrent and other sources too but the download never crosses even 1%. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to execute this commands in the command lines

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

After that you would able to run Android Studio and manage android-sdk

Hope it help